# Como liberar o servidor mysql para acesso externo?

Tags: mysql

Hospedei uma aplicação web utilizando o iis no windows server, porém preciso deixar o banco de dados online outras aplicações acessarem ele.

Como liberar o servidor mysql para acesso externo para que eu possa utilizar em outras aplicações?

É possível liberar utilizando o IIS? Estou utilizando o banco de dados MySql

Comment: qual é o banco de dados ?

Comment: Estou utilizando o banco de dados mysql

Comment: Se for uma hospedagem contratada você deve ver se eles fornecem mysql, caso contrário não terá como, se for um servidor o qual você tem total controle basta apontar o endereço do servidor mysql.

Comment: então... o banco não dá pra "hospedar no IIS", IIS é servidor WEB, vai fornecer serviços web...HTTP / FTP ... pro banco de dados estar online, basta estar instalado no servidor, e as conexões liberadas (rotas, firewall...) feito isso, estará "online" no ip público do servidor

Comment: Desconsiderei a questão da hospedagem contratada, porque na pergunta foi colocado "Hospedei ... no windows server".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tenho total acesso ao servidor, como descubro qual é o endereço ? Utilizo o mysql provido pelo xampp.

Comment: @TúlioParreiraCunha esta usando o `.env` do Laravel?

Comment: Tem sim. Consigo acessar o banco de dados localmente. Preciso acessa-lo fora do windows server.

Comment: Estou sim usando o .env do laravel, porém lá está localmente até o momento.

Comment: Vai ser uma maquina na mesma rede que vai acessar o teu mysql ou você quer acessar o mysql na "internet" (de qualquer computador conectado via ISP)?

Comment: Acessar na internet.

Comment: Tem alguma motivação em especial para acessar o mysql externamente? Parece não ter ligação com o laravel a sua duvida.

Comment: Irei criar uma nova pergunta e reformula-lá. Acho que não me expressei bem.

Comment: Ah não precisa de uma nova pergunta, deixa eu já entendi. Então me responde uma coisa, o Windows Server e a rede você tem permissão de liberar portas e firewall?